# :expo-updates:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin - React native and Expo

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I have already managed to build many versions of this same project and put it in the Google Play Store, but I am no longer able to do so with the new versions of the expo SDK etc. Currently, my dependency versions are these:

```
buildscript {
ext {
buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
if (findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')) {
kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')
}
frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

// We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1')
classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10')
}
}
```

`My Java JDK version is 21.0.2.`

And my gradle-wrapper.properties is this:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

And this is the error in the terminal:

```
Task :expo-updates:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler (in unnamed module @0x4af7ef06) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to unnamed module @0x4af7ef06
```

Or this error too:

```
Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
```

I tried switching versions of kotlin-gradle-plugin, android.tools.build:gradle and distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip I just tried to downgrade Java to 17 once and even more confusing errors appeared.

I tried switching between some other versions of the plugins and nothing. I changed the Java JDK version to 17 and then back.